# whereHas is not working on NULL value

Tags: api, eloquent, where-clause, laravel-5.5, eager-loading

in laravel 5.5 whereHas() is not working on where value is NULL. my relationship with other model is one to many and and i want to pick the values from the model where value is equal to NULL . But instead of returning the specific values its returning all the value in result

```
 plans = Plan::with('objectives')->with('objectives.keyResults')
           ->whereHas('objectives', function($query) {
               $query->whereNull('entity_id');
               $query->whereNull('quarter_id');
       })->where('companyKey', Auth::user()->companyKey)->get();
```

Comment: Do you mean that the eager loaded `objectives` contain all values?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir exactly objectives contain all the value and i want to filtered out the values where quarter_id is null, whereas in objectives i have quarter_id, entity_id, plan_id  as foreign keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the constraint twice:

```php
$plans = Plan::with(['objectives' => function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('entity_id');
        $query->whereNull('quarter_id');
    }, 'objectives.keyResults'])
    ->whereHas('objectives', function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('entity_id');
        $query->whereNull('quarter_id');
    })->where('companyKey', Auth::user()->companyKey)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

No double constraints are needed, simplify it to:

```
$plans = Plan::whereHas('objectives', function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('entity_id');
        $query->whereNull('quarter_id');
    })->with(['objectives'])
       ->where('companyKey', Auth::user()->companyKey)
       ->get();
```