# WhereHas Clause is not working..it gets all plans and my relatiion to plan and objectives is...plan has many objectives

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.5

```
plans = Plan::with('objectives')->with('objectives.keyResults')
           ->whereHas('objectives', function($query) {
               $query->whereNull('entity_id');
               $query->whereNull('quarter_id');
       })->where('companyKey', Auth::user()->companyKey)->get();
```

I want plans from objectives where entity_id,quarter_id is equal to null but whereHas is not working and it shows all plans. Relation of plans to objective is OneToMany and its Inverse is OneToOne.if there is a alternate to call null values please let me know

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528720/4848587 resolve this?

Comment: yes,this resolve my issue